# Trying to understand a program in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion

I'm trying to understand this kind of program in C, but I can't. Exactly, I can't figure out how *s is changed, and why the compiler shows 210012.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void WhatIamDoing(char *s) {
    char ch;
    if (*s) {
        ch = *s;
        s++;
        WhatIamDoing(s);
        putchar(ch);
    }
}


int main() {
        char s[20] = "012" ;
        WhatIamDoing(s) ;
        printf( "%s", s ) ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. This is no "explain the code" or tutoring site. See [ask].

Comment: @Olaf Who says that?

Comment: Have you heard of *recursion*? Specifically about *head recursion*?

Comment: "compiler shows 210012" -->  Does not your output include `l` and `k`?  Recommend posting output exactly.

Comment: @chux I did this for debugging.

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos: The stack overflow community. If you want to change that, ask on meta!

Comment: this is garbage value as the base element of char s is undefined.

Comment: @mssirvi No it is not.

Comment: he is printing printf( "%s", s ) ; s is the base element of the array . @EugeneSh.

Comment: Hint: How would you reverse a string/array using recursion?

Comment: @mssirvi What is the "base element"? `s` is defined and initialized.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i don't know.

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos Hint #2: You have this function in your code.

Comment: oh yes your are right @EugeneSh.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, I understand this.

Comment: Leaning the debug prints  in your original post, but including the true output would have helped explain this functionality.   Instead, now code is a moving target - unsure what it will be next.

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos So....? Just write down the program flow. You should notice that *all* of the recursive calls will be executed *before* the first character is printed.

Comment: @chux The code is this above. It is edited. Now it prints  210012

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, but when function  WhatIamDoing(s); is stopped called?

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos Look at the *`if`* condition.

Comment: @EugeneSh. *s what represents?

Comment: @StamatisPapadopoulos Now we are back to the basics? It's a character `s` is pointing to.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the first time  WhatIamDoing(s) is called how is *s?

Comment: It's the first character of the "original" `s`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers in C with recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287094/pointers-in-c-with-recursion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is easy to think this way. In void function `char *s` is a pointer that pointed to a `char` variable or char array. In your case it pointed to the char array `s[20]="012"`. In `WhatIamDoing` function `s` is pointed to `'0'` character and it's assign to `char ch` variable. Then `s++` now 's' is pointed to character `'1'`. Again you are calling the function `WhatIamDoing(s)`, it also happens the same (this is like a recursive function) and in the last `WhatIamDoing(s)`, `char ch` is assign as `'2'`. After all the characters are done, [image: functions running] (finally when it comes to null character) if condition is false. In last function by command `putchar` you print `'2'` then `'1'` then `'0'`. It means after you run the `WhatIamDoing` function you print the char array in reverse order. In main function you again print the s string. So then you get the the `"210021"`. hope you get the idea.

Comment: So, when *s is pointing to Null, if condition is get false. But why prints the array in reverse mode?

Comment: This is explained in answer - `putchar` prints characters of string in reversed order